Integration by substitution in Selberg's Integral
I am reading the article "Hilbert--Schmidt volume of the set of mixed quantum states" (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302197). I do not understand the step in which we start from (4.2) and get (4.1). It says: "Substituting $x^2_i = Λ_i$ we may bring the latter integral to the Gaussian form. Expressing it in the spherical coordinates
we get the integral (4.1) and eventually obtain..."
Could you give the detailed steps, or at least point out how we can get the integral in (4.1) from the integral in (4.2). I cannot see the connection between the two integrals or understand how to transform one into the other.
(Context: integral in (4.2) is a special form of Selberg's Integral (Laguerre type) it can be found on page 321 in the book Mehta: Random Matrices-Academic Press, 2004)


looks like some exponential representation of the $\delta$ function was used

That was my first guess too, but I can't see how.

Here is a possible approach, I admit I didn't work it completely through:
Consider $$G(z)=\int (d\Lambda_1\cdots d\Lambda_N)\delta(\sum\Lambda_i - z)\cdots$$ ($G(1)$ is our integral).
We can scale out the $z$ so that $$G(z)=z^\gamma G(1)$$ for some value of $\gamma$.
Now lets Laplace transform $G(z)$
$$\hat G(q)=\int_0^{\infty}dz e^{-qz}G(z)=G(1)\int_0^{\infty}dz e^{-qz}z^\gamma $$
We can integrate out the $\delta$ to get
$$\hat G(q)=\int (d\Lambda_1\cdots d\Lambda_N)e^{-q\sum\Lambda_i}\cdots$$
and setting $q=1$ we can relate $$\hat G(1) = G(1)\int_0^{\infty}dz e^{-z}z^\gamma $$
